# Qual a expressão equivalente a "Você não existe!" em Portugal?

Tags: ortografia, expressões-equivalentes

No Brasil é comum ouvirmos na linguagem coloquial a expressão "Você não existe!". Funciona como adjetivo e possui os seguintes sentidos: você é uma pessoa especial, única, sensacional, ainda não te inventaram.

Exemplo:

> Muito obrigado, você não existe!
>   Após uma piada ou comentário. Hahahahaha, você é demais, não existe!

Qual a expressão equivalente a "Você não existe!" em Portugal?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Em Portugal dizemos **"tu não existes"**, é só trocar o sujeito para o estilo pt_PT.

Answer (score 0):

Expressão para "Você não existe", concretamente, não me vem à memória. No lugar de "Cara, você não existe" Podes ser mais objetivo e dizer do tipo "Meu/Mano/Bacano, tu és o maior"/tu és do caralho/tu és um patrão/ tu és um senhor